# Changing Azure Backup Retention policy not reducing Azure storage used?

Tags: azure, storage

We started using Microsoft Azure Backup on our Windows servers, as a means for off-site, disaster recovery backup.  The service has been running for about 9 months now, and we noticed each month's bill was higher than the last.  When we looked into it - we were surprised how much space we were using - a single server's backups were using over 850GB of storage in Azure now.  Loading the Azure Backup client on the server, we noticed it was set to 180 days retention, with additional weekly/monthly/yearly backups.  Given that this was entirely unnecessary for our purposes - this is really just a secondary, worst-case-scenario backup - we changed the retention to 30 days, and un-checked the boxes for weekly/monthly/etc.

The MS Azure Backup client now shows the retention rate as being 30 days.  When we log into the Azure portal, it now shows the policy as being 30 days.  The storage used, however, hasn't changed.  We implemented these changes yesterday, and today we're using another few GB of space - the equivalent of the last day's backups.  The Azure Portal says our oldest available backup is 30 days ago - as expected - so why is it still using all that space, and how do we release it?

Comment: Any news on this?